# how can I convert my String (that represents hex values) to bytes?

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

I have a String in `Java` that contains 32 characters:

```
String tempHash = "123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF12";
```

Each character in the String above represents a hex value. I need to convert it to another String, that contains 8-bytes calculated by each hex from the string above. So in the example from above, the output string would be:

```
"00000001 00000010 00000011 000001000 000001001 000001011 ..."
```

how can I do that?

I tried to do:

```
byte[] bytes1 = toByteArray(tempHash);
```

where

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
}
```

but when I iterate over this array:

```
for (byte singleByte: bytes1) {
    System.out.println(singleByte);
}
```

for the first character I'm getting `18` instead of `00000001`. 
I'm a little bit lost over here. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: The [`DatatypeConverter#parseHexBinary`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/DatatypeConverterImpl.java.html) builtin method decodes the String per 2 characters (see the `i+=2` in the loop of the `parseHexBinary` method on line 358 of the link I provided). The same applies to most Java builtins, like `new java.math.BigInteger(str, 16).toByteArray()`. I was about to write an answer suggesting to do a manual conversion per character, but _@JacobG_ already provided an excellent (Java 11+) stream answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a `Stream`:

```
String tempHash = "123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF12";

String binary = tempHash.chars()              // Get stream of chars
    .map(c -> Character.digit(c, 16))         // Convert to hex digit
    .mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString)        // Convert to binary
    .map(s -> "0".repeat(8 - s.length()) + s) // Pad left with zeros
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));        // Collect to String

System.out.println(binary);
```

Output:

```
00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 00000101 ...
```

---

As [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682559/kevin-cruijssen) pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153453/how-can-i-convert-my-string-that-represents-hex-values-to-bytes/60153673#comment106393259_60153673) below, a pre-Java 11 solution would be to replace the call to [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)):

```
String binary = tempHash.chars()              // Get stream of chars
    .map(c -> Character.digit(c, 16))         // Convert to hex digit
    .mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString)        // Convert to binary
    .map(s -> new String(new char[8 - s.length()]).replace('\0', '0') + s) // Pad left with zeros
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));        // Collect to String
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks clean and smooth, one question - seems like I don't have the repeat function... is there any other way to do so without the repeat then?

Comment: @randomuser1 `String#repeat` was added in Java 11. I'll modify my answer to add a pre-Java 11 solution.

Comment: `new String(new char[8 - s.length()]).replace('\0', '0')` is what I used to use prior to Java 11. Nice answer btw, @JacobG. I was about to write an answer myself, but yours is better than the non-stream answer I was preparing.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Was just about to write that in my answer; thanks!

Comment: @JacobG. could you please update your answer to pre-java11, so that I could accept it? :) thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, not only it works, but it also looks clean!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Long.parseLong(String,16);`

Once you have a `long` value, you can get the bytes by doing

```
long val = ...;
ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer();
buf.put(0, val);
```

If your string is too long you will need to use a BigInteger. It's essentially the same thing, but a little more complicated

Comment: This wouldn't separate each digit into 8 bit sections as his output example shows.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I was answering the question as presented in the title. In any case, this is as simple as Integer.toBinaryString(val)

Answer (score -1):

```
public byte hexToByte(String hexString) {
    int firstDigit = toDigit(hexString.charAt(0));
    int secondDigit = toDigit(hexString.charAt(1));
    return (byte) ((firstDigit << 4) + secondDigit);
}

private int toDigit(char hexChar) {
    int digit = Character.digit(hexChar, 16);
    if(digit == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Invalid Hexadecimal Character: "+ hexChar);
    }
    return digit;
}
```

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-byte-arrays-hex-strings) is the reference

Comment: Op is asking to convert hex to a byte value but not to convert to Hex value